# How to use $_SESSION to pass on values from multiple pages and $_POST together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I have sequence of forms on different pages and want to temporary store the values across all the pages and mail them once all the forms have been filled in.

Apparently $_SESSION is the best way??? Here's what I got:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Whats your name?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="two.php" method="post">
        Fav color:<br>
        <input name="color" type="text" value="blue"><br>
        Fav sport:<br>
        <input name="sport" type="text" value="soccer"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

two.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Where do you live?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        Shoe size:<br>
        <input name="size" type="text" value="4"><br>
        left or right handed?:<br>
        <input name="hand" type="text" value="left"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

post.php

```
<?php

$to  = "myemail@host.com";
$sub = "Testing session out";

mail($to, $sub, $message);

header('Location: finish.php');

?>
```

finish.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Thanks</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL='http://new-website.com' " />
</head>

<body>
<p>All done, thanks</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I want "post.php" to mail all the values to my email in one go e.g.

```
$message = $_POST['color'];
$message .= $_POST['sport'];
$message .= $_POST['size'];
$message .= $_POST['hand'];
```

Comment: you have an out of scope issue here.

Comment: *"Apparently $_SESSION is the best way?"* - Yes. However, you can do this without sessions and just use all the inputs in one form.

Comment: page 2 you store the post values in a session from page one. in post you session values(p1) and post values(p2) to send email

Comment: Don't bother with 'thanks guys' and all that friendly stuff. Doesn't matter. We're all over the world and don't know each other. We're all just helping people and making the site better. Millions of questions. No time for hey and howdy each time. No offense, and nothing personal - to you, or from you :-)

Comment: noted @clearlight

Comment: since you're being cool about it and all, check out how this amazing place works. Look at the review link at the top where people review and help moderate and improve quality of questions (where we saw yours first), and the help link about asking questions and *take the tour* so you can find out about the rep points and badge trinkets we get that seem like kindergarten gold stars but really represent tangible contributions, and also the perks in terms of access given for making contributions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `$_POST` to `$_SESSION`

```
<?php

$_SESSION['firstname']  = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['lastname']  = $_POST['lastname'];

?>
```

but in "post.php" you can't call firstname and lastname with post,

```
$message = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$message .= $_SESSION['lastname'];
$message .= $_POST['door'];
$message .= $_POST['zip'];
```

don't forget to use `session_start` at the beginning script

or you can add again to tag `input` without `$_SESSION` inside form

```
<input name="firstname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>" />
<input name="lastname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?>" />
```

Comment: can I not  say $_POST ['firstname'] = $_SESSION['firstname']; ?

Comment: what page would I can session_start?

Comment: don't do this, there's no meaning doing it  `$_POST['firstname'] = $_SESSION['firstname']`

use session_start in two.php and post.php because just that page that will use $_SESSION.